# Necessary and sufficient condition for two components of least square estimate to be negatively correlated

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, variance, covariance, least-squares

Consider a linear model in a matrix form $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$ where $Y$ is a response vector, $X$ is a $n$ by $p$ ($p < n$) full rank matrix of predictors, $\beta$ is a parameter vector, and $\epsilon$ is an error vector whose components are i.i.d. with a variance of $\sigma^2 > 0$.

(a) Derive the variance-covariance matrix of $\hat{\beta}$, the least square estimator of $\beta$.

(b) Let $X$ be given by the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1\\
1 & x_2\\
. & .\\
. & .\\
. & .\\
1 & x_n
\end{bmatrix}

Determine the necessary and sufficient condition for the two components of $\hat{\beta}$ being negatively correlated.

Here are my thoughts so far:

Part (a) has been asked on this network quite a bit, so sparing the details, one can work out that the variance-covariance matrix of $\hat{\beta}$ is  given by $(X'X)^{-1} \cdot \sigma^2$ (where the prime symbol here represents the transpose).

Now, for part (b), let $\beta = (\beta_1, \beta_2)'$, and let $\hat{\beta} = (\hat{\beta_1}, \hat{\beta_2})'$ be the LSE of $\beta$. Then we have covariance matrix given by

$(X'X)^{-1} \cdot \sigma^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
n & \sum_{i = 1}^nx_i\\
\sum_{i = 1}^nx_i & \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2
\end{bmatrix}\sigma^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
Var(\hat{\beta_1}) & Cov(\hat{\beta_1} \hat{\beta_2})\\
Cov(\hat{\beta_1} \hat{\beta_2}) & Var(\hat{\beta_2})
\end{bmatrix}\sigma^2$

Now, I believe that the two components $\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2}$ of $\hat{\beta}$ are negatively correlated *if and only if* $Cov(\hat{\beta_1}, \hat{\beta_2})$ is negative. Following this thought, since $\sigma^2$ is positive, this means that $\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2}$ are negatively correlated in our case if and only if $\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i < 0$. Thus, the necessary and sufficient condition for the two components of $\hat{\beta}$ being negatively correlated is $\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i < 0$.

Is this a correct solution ? Or can I take this further to express a more desirable condition for my solution ?

Thanks for your time !

Comment: This looks correct.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!